# Javascript working on Firefox but not in Chrome and IE6

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, getelementbyid

I have javascript that working fine in Firefox 3.x.x, but it does not work in IE*, Chrome, Safari. Simple alert work before calling function. Here is the code

```
function showDiv(div){
 //alert(div);
 document.getElementById(div).style.visibility='visible';
 document.getElementById(div).style.height='auto';
 document.getElementById(div).style.display='block';}
function hideDiv(div){
 //alert(div);
 document.getElementById(div).style.visibility='hidden';
 document.getElementById(div).style.height='0px';
 document.getElementById(div).style.display='none';
}
```

here is the html page code

```
<td align="center"><a onclick="showDiv('<?=$val['keyname']?>')" style="cursor:pointer;">Edit</a></td>
```

if I put `alert()` before `showDiv('<?=$val['keyname']?>')` then alert box is displayed but the function is not called in other browsers other than fire fox

Please tell me the solution for this.

Comment: You may be getting errors in the error console. Please always include those, or state that there are none.

Comment: Can you tell me more about what Not working means?  Is it a javascript error, do these functions do nothing at all?  Please elaborate on the not working part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing inherently wrong in the code you have posted. I suggest you post a reproduceable non-working example: the problem will be elsewhere in the page. Maybe the `div` ID string isn't unique (this is invalid HTML and will make behaviour unreliable); maybe there's some other script interfering, maybe you have event code firing this that's not written in a cross-browser way

However your attempts to hide an element in three different ways seem like overkill to me. Just a single `display` change would do it fine.

Another way to do it is to set `className='hidden'` or `''`, and use a CSS rule to map that class to `display: none`. The advantage of this is that you don't have to know whether the element in question is a `<div>` (that should revert to `display: block`), a `<span>` (that should revert to `display: inline`) or something else. (The table-related elements have particular problems.)

Answer (score 3):

The syntax looks okay to me.

Make sure there are not multiple elements with the same ID in the document and that your element IDs are valid.

Comment: Good point!  Also ensure that the case is correct.  As some browsers are case sensitive (when it comes to ids) and some are not.

Comment: yes, I'm sure there is no multiple elements with same name in one page.All elements have different  id's.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try that:

```
function showDiv(div) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(div);
    if (obj) {
        obj.style.display = "block";
        obj.style.height = "auto";
    } else {
       alert("DIV with id " + div + " not found. Can't show it.");
    }
}

function hideDiv(div) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(div);
    if (obj) {
        obj.style.display = "none";
    } else {
       alert("DIV with id " + div + " not found. Can't hide it.");
    }
}
```

Do not call `document.getElementById` several times in the same function, use a variable to store the `div` element.

The `if (obj)` test will only execute the code if it has been found by `document.getElementById(...)`.

Comment: This shouldn't matter, also, display: none acts differently than visibility, as display none takes the dom element out of the layout flow, while visibility hidden simply makes it invisible.

Comment: @Zoidberg sorry, my answer was posted too quickly, it was not the only thing I wanted to suggest...

Comment: I agree with this answer - if you're setting display:block/none, that should be all you need to do; you shouldn't need to touch visibility or height to make the box appear and disappear.