# Hide element with Javascript. Doesn't work with IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, show-hide

I have problems with hiding elements.
I already read this topic 
[Javascript working on Firefox but not in Chrome and IE6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675870/javascript-working-on-firefox-but-not-in-chrome-and-ie6)
but didn't get help from there. Javascript code, what should hide/show textbox and radio buttons:

```
function hide1(a)
{
var text1=document.getElementById("text1");
text1.style.visibility = 'visible';
text1.value = a;

document.getElementById("radio1").style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementById("radio2").style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementById("rlabel").style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

function show1()
{
document.getElementById("text1").style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementById("radio1").style.visibility = 'visible';
document.getElementById("radio2").style.visibility = 'visible';
document.getElementById("rlabel").style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

And HTML:

```
<select id='listb2'>
  <option onclick='hide1("$age");' value='1'>Age</option>
  <option onclick='show1();' value='2'>Sex</option>
</select>
```

Now with Firefox and Opera it change radio buttons and textbox to visible/hidden when I choose one of the options. But with Chrome and IE they wouldn't. I also tried with "... .style.display = 'none';" nothing happened (on IE and Chrome, FF and Opera it works) even this time.

FF 5.0; Chrome 12; IE 8; Opera 11.50

Now works with:

```
<select onchange='hideshow(this.value);' id='listb2'>
  <option value='1'>Age</option>
  <option value='2'>Sex</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Does a `<option onclick>` fire at all? Try alerting something inside `hide1`.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`onclick` isn't valid for `option` elements.

Handle the `onchange` event of the `select` instead, get the selected value using the code below and then do your conditional processing.

```
var element = document.getElementById("listb2");
var selectedValue = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
```

Comment: `select` doesn't work and with `onchange` I had some problems aswell

Comment: @Timo: `onchange` is in the HTML4 spec for `select`: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.6 What were the problems?

Comment: Yeah now I got it, dont know what I was thinking :D. But onchange there where still problems last time. I'll check once more.

Comment: Thank you everyone, onchange working well, maybe I made some mistakse last time.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of setting 'visibility' to 'hidden', try setting 'display' to 'none'.

```
document.getElementById('header').style.display = 'none';
```

---

EDIT: Not quite sure whether you can set the `onclick` property on an `option` element in those browsers... Try using `onchange` on your surrounding `select` tag instead.

Comment: Actually I'm using it already, I posted older code because I was sure its working. Now I'm sure `display` also work with FF and Opera

Answer (score 1):

I realy encourage you to use jQuery for that. jQuery guarantees that this will work in every browser. In query its very easy

```
<script>
    $().ready(function () {
        $("#listb2").change(function () {
            if ($("#listb2").val() == "1")
                $("#radio1, #radio2, #rlabel").show();
            else
                $("#text1, #radio1, #radio2, #rlabel").hide();
        });
    });
</script>

<select id='listb2'>
  <option value='1'>Age</option>
  <option value='2'>Sex</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the onclick events from the select box like this:

```
<select id='listb2'>
  <option value='1'>Age</option>
  <option value='2'>Sex</option>
</select>
```

Then you can bind an onChange event using javascript:

```
var selectBox = document.getElementById("listb2");
selectBox.onchange = function(e){
    if(selectBox.value == 1) {
        // Do what you want for Age
        hide1();
    } else if(selectBox.value == 2) {
        // Do what you want for Sex
        show1();
    }
}
```